# SQL Server Reporting Services subscription creation silently fails. No error message is displayed, but the subscription does not get created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

I'm trying to set up a subscription for a SSRS report.  I have deployed the report to the server and I can view the report in a web browser with no problems.  I have tried to reproduce this issue on other servers and I cannot get it to fail in the same way on any other server that I have tried.

Here are the steps I am taking to create the subscription:

1. On the server, run Internet Explorer as an administrator.
2. Browse to http://localhost/reports
3. Navigate to the report that I want to create a subscription for.
4. Click on the dropdown arrow next to the report name and click "Subscribe."
5. Configure all the appropriate settings.
6. Click "OK."

At this point, I am taken back to the folder which contains the report, as if the subscription was successfully created, with no errors displayed or any confirmation that it was successful or unsuccessful.  However, if I click "My Subscriptions" at the top of the page, there are no subscriptions displayed.

I have also tried creating a shared schedule, and configuring the subscription to use the shared schedule.  When I do this, I can see that the schedule is in fact being executed, but the subscription was never created and therefore never executed.

I have repeated these same steps on several other servers and I cannot reproduce the issue.  Unfortunately, I need to get it working on this particular server.

At this point, I can only assume that either there is a problem with the SQL Server installation on this server, or that I have configured something wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<your instance name>\Reporting Services\LogFiles`, perhaps you can find some clues there.